# Loop nested objects AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, nested

```
{

    name: 'Product One',
    visibility: 1,
    weight: '0.5',
    price: '19.99'
    custom_attributes: [
        {
            attribute_code: 'image',
            value: '.img'
        },
        {
            attribute_code: 'special_price',
            value: '13.99'
        }
    ]

},
{

    name: 'Product One',
    visibility: 1,
    weight: '0.5',
    price: '19.99'
    custom_attributes: [
        {
            attribute_code: 'image',
            value: '.img'
        },
        {
            attribute_code: 'special_price',
            value: '13.99'
        }
    ]

}
```

How do I get access to 'special_price' value on ng-repeat or javascript?

Comment: You can do like : let obj of list for ng repeat and Then let obj1 of obj.custom_attribute

Comment: You want that attribute_code key`s value?

Comment: Yes. Retrieve value: 13.99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways you could approach this.

### Prepare the data in the controller

```
function ExampleCtrl (products) {
  this.$onChanges = (changes) => {
    if (changes.products) {
    this.specialProductPrices = this.products.reduce((map, product) => {
      map[product.id] = product.custom_attributes
        // @TODO: Account for a case when there is no special price.
        .find(({attribute_code}) => attribute_code === 'special_price').value;
      return map;
    }, {})
    }
  }
}

angular.module('foo').component('example', {
  bindings: {
    products: '<'
  },
  controller: [
    ExampleCtrl
  ],
  template: `
    <div ng-repeat="product in $ctrl.products track by product.id">
      Name: <span ng-bind="product.name"></span>
      Price: <span ng-bind="product.price"></span>
      Special Price: <span ng-bind="$ctrl.specialProductPrices[product.id]"></span>
    </div>
  `
})
```

And then the component can simply be used as `<example products="products"></example>`. This is mostly an idiomatic approach in angularjs land,
and overall encouraged due to the use of components + reducers which prepare the data once rather than looping multiple times during every $digest cycle.

### Access it within the loop in template

If you *have* to do this in the template, you could do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in $ctrl.products track by product.id">
  Name: <span ng-bind="product.name"></span>
  Price: <span ng-bind="product.price"></span>
  Special Price:
  <span>
    <span ng-repeat="customAttribute in product.custom_attributes track by customAttribute.attribute_code"
      ng-show="customAttributeattribute_code === 'special_price'"
      ng-bind="customAttribute.value">
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

However this method isn't encouraged, since it creates DOM elements which will never be shown (`ng-if` can't be used in this case due to the repeater.). Additionally if there are many custome attributes,
this will become *very* inefficient.

### Other options

One could also potentially create components which take in `product.custom_attributes` and show the attribute if present, or create a filter which would pick the attribute out as well.
These methods are left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I'm getting  Unexpected token: operator (>)

Comment: Are you using ES6 and have support for arrow functions? If not, replace all instances of `() => ` to a standard function declaration

Comment: All good, it gulp-uglify that was causing it. Thanks!